# How to remove 0 from front of the numbers in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

Remove the 0s. For ex: 01, 001, 0001, 00001 and so on should become 1 in Textbox either automatically or using a button. Please help!

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`String.TrimStart`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.trimstart):

```
txtNumber.Text = txtNumber.Text.TrimStart({"0"c})
```

In case also "0" should be a valid input on the `TextBox` you can use a solution using [`Integer.TryParse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse#System_Int32_TryParse_System_String_System_Int32__) or [`Decimal.TryParse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal.tryparse#System_Decimal_TryParse_System_String_System_Decimal__):

```
'solution using Integer.TryParse
Dim intValue As Integer = 0
Integer.TryParse(txtNumber.Text, intValue)
txtNumber.Text = intValue

'solution using Decimal.TryParse
Dim decValue As Decimal = 0.0
Decimal.TryParse(txtNumber.Text, decValue)
txtNumber.Text = decValue
```